# JMeter CSV datasource tilde character becomes null

Tags: jmeter

I am reading variables from a CSV datasource. My typical line is:

1234567890;~

Problem is the tilde is making the second variable null in JMeter. If I replace with this it works:

1234567890;123

I Need the tiled to work because its part of our MVC URL design. Is there an escape or something?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the following data it worked for me:

```
1234567890;~
1234567890;123
```

view results tree:

[image]

CSV Config:
[image]

Usage in HTTP sampler:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I see some French in your JMeter GUI so it might be something connected with [file encoding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html), the universal one is [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)

1. To verify the encoding:

   - Add [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) to your Test Plan and configure it to display `System Properties`

     [image: Debug Sampler System Properties]
   - Add [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener and look for `file.encoding` property value

     [image: file.encoding property]
2. To set the encoding use one of the following approaches

   - add the next line to *system.properties* file (located in JMeter's "bin" folder)

     ```
     file.encoding=UTF-8
     ```
   - you can also do the same via `-D` command-line argument (see [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for details)

     ```
     jmeter -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -n -t ....
     ```

---

If above steps don't help it might be a problem with your CSV file (some invisible control character, missing line break, etc)